# Simple ValueError in a single quadrotor navigation code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, valueerror

I'm having a newbie error with a simple piece of code of a flying quadrotor. The error I read is "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4) on line:

```
States[0:6], Thrust_calc, z_accel, x_accel, y_accel= quadrotor(States,S_desired[6:11],Thrust)
```

I have the code divided in two files. The involved lines are coded are shown next:

```
for j in range(N):
        
x_vel_desired = (final_x_coordinate - States[6])/(50*dt)
x_accel_desired = 0
y_vel_desired = (final_y_coordinate - States[7])/(50*dt)
y_accel_desired = 0

S_desired[0], S_desired[1], S_desired[2] = final_x_coordinate,x_vel_desired,x_accel_desired
S_desired[3], S_desired[4], S_desired[5] = final_y_coordinate,y_vel_desired,y_accel_desired

#DESIRED ANGLE
#Theta
S_desired[6] = angle_objective(S_desired[0:3],States[6],States[9],States[0],Thrust,Kxp1,Kxd1)

#Phi
S_desired[7] = angle_objective(S_desired[3:7],States[7],States[10],States[1],Thrust,Kyp1,Kyd1)


#DRONE height position, velocity and acceleration
#OBTAINING OF THE STATES OF THE QUADROTOR
States[0:6], Thrust_calc, z_accel, x_accel, y_accel= quadrotor(States,S_desired[6:11],Thrust)

#the increment of the thrust is smooth
if Thrust_calc-Thrust>0.05:
    Thrust=Thrust_calc+0.05
elif Thrust-Thrust_calc>0.05:
    Thrust=Thrust_calc-0.05
            

#OBTAINTION OF X_POS AND X_VEL
States[9],States[6]  = EulerIntegration(x_accel,States[9],States[6])
States[10],States[7] = EulerIntegration(y_accel,States[10],States[7])
```

and the other file is:

```
def quadrotor(States, desired_states, Thrust):
inputs=[0]*4
#desired_states=list(map(int, desired_states))
#PID Values
Kp, Ki, Kd = 4.05, 0, 20.64

Torque=[0]*4

#pid controller. Roll = 0
err_phi=desired_states[1]-States[1] 
Torque[1]=(err_phi*Kp + err_phi*Ki*dt - States[4]*Kd*dt )* I[0,0] 

#PID Controller. Pitch = 0
err_theta=desired_states[0]-States[0]
Torque[2]=(err_theta*Kp + err_theta*Ki*dt - States[3]*Kd*dt) * I[1,1]

#PID Controller. Yaw = 0
err_yaw=desired_states[2]-States[2]
Torque[3]=(err_yaw*Kp + err_yaw*Ki*dt - States[5]*Kd*dt ) * I[2,2] 

#PID Controller. Height error = 0
err_height=desired_states[3]-States[8]
Torque[0]=err_height*Kp + err_height*Ki*dt - States[8]*Kd*dt + (m*g)/(math.cos(States[1])*math.cos(States[0])) 
if Torque[0]>8:
    Torque[0]=8
elif Torque[0]<3:
    Torque[0]=3
  
#inputs
inputs[0]= 1/(4*k)*Torque[0] - 1/(2*k*L)*Torque[2] - 1/(4*b)*Torque[3] 
inputs[1]= 1/(4*k)*Torque[0] - 1/(2*k*L)*Torque[1] + 1/(4*b)*Torque[3] 
inputs[2]= 1/(4*k)*Torque[0] + 1/(2*k*L)*Torque[2] - 1/(4*b)*Torque[3] 
inputs[3]= 1/(4*k)*Torque[0] + 1/(2*k*L)*Torque[1] + 1/(4*b)*Torque[3] 

phi_acel=    Torque[1]/I[0,0] 
theta_acel=  Torque[2]/I[1,1] 
psi_acel=    Torque[3]/I[2,2] 

theta_vel, theta = EulerIntegration(theta_acel,States[3],States[0])
phi_vel, phi =     EulerIntegration(phi_acel,States[4],States[1])
psi_vel, psi =     EulerIntegration(psi_acel,States[5],States[2])

z_accel= -g + (math.cos(theta)*math.cos(phi))*Torque[0]/m
x_accel=(math.sin(psi)*math.sin(phi)+math.cos(psi)*math.sin(theta)*math.cos(phi))*Torque[0]/m

results= [theta, phi, psi, theta_vel, phi_vel, psi_vel]

return results, Torque[0], z_accel, x_accel
```

Whole code is [published here](https://github.com/Julestevez/Quadrotor-simulator/tree/master/Horizontal%20control%20of%20a%20quadrotor). Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: The function returns a 4-tuple, and you're trying to unpack 5 values from it. You should try to rethink what you are trying to get from the function.

Comment: ok, now i see that I need to define y_accel in the second piece of code. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I saw finally that I have to define "y_accel" and include it in the "return" line of variables